# Apache Beam unable to identify global function in script GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working on a project to create a stream processing prediction engine on GCP. I am mostly learning from this repo [here](https://github.com/TDehaene/blogposts/tree/master/got_sentiment). However when I try to execute the script blogposts/got_sentiment/4_streaming_pipeline/streaming_tweet.py I keep getting error

```
NameError: name 'estimate' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-129']
```

My function looks like as follows

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import datetime
import json
import logging

import numpy as np

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.transforms.window as window
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions, GoogleCloudOptions, SetupOptions, PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.util import BatchElements

from googleapiclient import discovery

def init():
    ........

def estimate_cmle():

   init()
   .....

def estimate(instances):

   estimate_cmle()
   ......


def run(argv=None):
....

   output = (lines
                     | 'assign window key' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10))
                     | 'batch into n batches' >> BatchElements(min_batch_size=49, max_batch_size=50)
                     | 'predict sentiment' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda messages: estimate(messages))
                     )

.....


f __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

This is where beam seems to unable to to recognize the estimate function although I am creating it in the same script.

**Edit**

Trying with `beam.FlatMap(estimate)` gave error

```
name 'estimate_cmle' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-1208']
```

Comment: Have you tried doing beam.FlatMap(estimate) instead of beam.FlatMap(lambda messages: estimate(messages))?

Comment: I tried. Now it is giving me estimate_cmle not found :(

Comment: Where and how are you using estimate_cmle?

Comment: Inside the estimate function the estimate_cmle is being used to call the model API on CMLE to get prediction

Comment: Which python version are you using? I saw the code on github and it is supposed to work

Comment: I am using python3

Comment: Are you defining the function as def estimate_cmle(instances) and calling it as estimate_cmle([instance["text"] for instance in instances]) just like in GitHub?

Comment: Yes I am using the exact function

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your error, For now just make sure that the function is used after its definition

Comment: Thanks a lot. That will be of great help as I am very new to using beam. I have currently use the code as it is by changing the project, the staging bucket, the topic, subscription and the model location specific to my account

Comment: @rmesteves were you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm trying but I get another error:  AttributeError: module 'apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients.bigquery' has no attribute 'TableFieldSchema'

It seems that this library is not updated at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206283/discussion-between-rajarshi-bhadra-and-rmesteves).

Comment: @Rajarshi Bhadra, Did you fix the issue reported? or investigation is still ongoing?

Answer (score 0):

Look at these 2 parts:

Function definition

```
def estimate(instances):
......
```

Function call

```
beam.FlatMap(lambda messages: estimate(messages,estimate_cmle))
```

Your call expect a function with 2 parameters, your declared function have only one. Your python script only contain an estimate with 1 parameter and the function with 2 parameters is not defined.

The examples, in the repo, the call contain only 1 parameter and thus it works. Fix this, it should work then

Comment: Sorry that was from something I was trying. Even without the arguement I get the same error